# Why is my Line Chart.JS starting in the middle?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to add some JS chart to my webpage, but somehow the line starts in the middle of the graph. (No matter how many data points there are)

See Below:

There are only 3 data points, but the line starts only at the very end. And only one label shows up even there are 3 data point

[image: Example]

Does anyone have any idea why?  Thanks!

Code:

> ```
>  // Line chart
>   var ctx = document.getElementById("instance_countChart");
>   var instance_countChart = new Chart(ctx, {
>     type: 'line',
>     data: {
>       labels: [
>        "gukumar_skb_regression_03_17_17_23.45",
>
>        "gukumar_skb_regression_03_18_17_23.45",
>
>        "gukumar_skb_regression_03_19_17_23.45",
>                 ],
>       datasets: [{
>       label: "instance_count",
>         backgroundColor: "transparent",
>         borderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
>         pointBorderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
>         pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
>         pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
>         pointBorderWidth: 1,
>       //backgroundColor: "#26B99A",
>       data: [  7409085.0,  7409085.0,  7409041.0,
>     ]
>     }]
>     },
>
>
>   });
> ```

How I am calling it:

```
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="x_panel">
            <div class="x_title">
              <h2>instancecount </h2>
              <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="x_content">
              <canvas id="instance_countChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try using short labels to see if it works (e.g. `labels: ['label 1', 'label 2', 'label 3']`).  I'm guessing it cant correctly​ fit the long labels and its causing weird overflow issues.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it happens, after reading the documentation, and doing some experiments.  If I turn off the XAxes, the line starts from the beginning. But with the Axes label on, I am still not able to get it correctly.

```
   options: {
       scales: {
           xAxes: [{
               display: false
           }]
       }
   }
```